# Attach content of a div inside tooltip

Tags: javascript, java, dojo, tooltip, dijit.form

I have a div **previewBox** with one **inputBox(input)** and one **Button(byUser )** I am trying to connect the tooltip to **prevBtn**, and I want my inputbox and button inside my tooltip.I know how to connect the tooltip to a div, but I am confused on how to insert the inputbox to the tooltip. If we can add an input box to a tooltip, please provide the necessary information.
Thank you.

```
var prevBtn = dojo.create("span", {innerHTML:"<a></a>Preview", className:"txtLink icon search"}, btnWrapr1);
var previewBox = dojo.create('div', { className: 'prevBox'}, this.rootNode);
            var input = new dijit.form.TextBox({
                required:true, 
                value: "",
                maxLength: 32,
                style: { width: 100+'px' } 
            }).placeAt(previewBox);
            var byUser = new at.common.form.Button({
                label: "Preview",
                onClick: dojo.hitch(this, function() {
                    //TODO
                })          
            }).placeAt(previewBox);  
            var tt = new dijit.Tooltip({
                connectId: [prevBtn],
                position: ['above'],
                getContent:[input]          
            });
```

I can provide any further details if there is any confusion.Thanks

Comment: What dojo version do you use?

Comment: Thank you so much for responding. I am using dojo-1.6.1 and i am still not able configure this. I really wanted to get some idea to add an input box to a tooltip if its possible. Thank you

Comment: ok, I work with 1.10 that is a little bit different than 1.6
can you post all code necessary to try the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help

```
addTooltip: function(tt, message) {
            var thisObj = this;
            var btt = new dijit.Tooltip({
              label: message,
              connectId: tt,
              position: ['above']
            });      
        var previewBox = dojo.create('div', { className: 'prevBox'}, tt);
             var input = new dijit.form.TextBox({
                    required:true, 
                    value: "",
                    maxLength: 32,
                    style: { width: 100+'px' } 
                }).placeAt(previewBox);
              var byUser = new dijit.form.Button({
                    label: "Preview",
                    onClick: dojo.hitch(this, function() {
                        //TODO
                    })          
                }).placeAt(previewBox); 

           dojo.connect(this, "onMouseOver", this, function(evt) { 
      this.cancelTooltip = false;
      window.setTimeout( function(){ 
        if (!thisObj.cancelTooltip) 
          btt.open(previewBox); }, 400);
    });
            dojo.connect(this, "onMouseDown", this, function(evt) { 
                this.cancelTooltip = true;
                window.setTimeout( function(){ btt.close(); }, 100);      
              });
            dojo.connect(this, "onMouseLeave", this, function(evt) { 
              this.cancelTooltip = true;
              window.setTimeout( function(){ btt.close(); }, 1000);      
            });
          },
```